# For-Loop over (pd.read_pickle) DataFrame does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I want to store a very big csv File as a pickle, so that I don't need to read the csv file every time I run my code. That is how I do that:

```
df_log = pd.read_csv("Val_Nissan_Leaf/oneyearLeafLog.txt", delimiter=",", 
header=0)
df_log.to_pickle("Val_Nissan_Leaf/df_log_pickled.pkl")
```

After that I just want to iterate over the DatFrame. The Problem is, that the Code runs forever, because it kind of stops before the for loop. If I want to print the DataFrame it works, and the type is: 
 as well.

```
df_log = pd.read_pickle("Val_Nissan_Leaf/df_log_pickled.pkl")
j = 0

for lab, row in df_log.iterrows():
    j +=1
    print(j)
```

If I convert the csv file to a dataframe directly, it works as well.
Does anyone know what might be the Problem

Comment: UPDATE: the for loop starts, but only after about two minutes. Why is that so?

Comment: `iterrows` is slow, try `itertuples` instead. It may still be too slow.

Comment: If your data is mostly text using pickles might be slower than just using csv:

http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2015/03/16/Fast-Serialization